# Proper and safest way to verify that it was really you that made the order during a guest checkout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, shopping-cart

What is the proper and safest way to verify that it was really you that made the order during a guest checkout?

Example from MVC Music Store App to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

```
//    
// GET: /Checkout/Complete

public ActionResult Complete(int id)
{
    // Validate customer owns this order
    bool isValid = storeDB.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderId == id && o.Username == User.Identity.Name);

    if (isValid)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Notice the line bool isValid. Here you're making two checks. 1. Check if the order exist in the Orders table. 2. Verify that the customer owns the order. 
But this is for a user that has previously registered him/herself.

So how to make the same type of verification but using guest checkout (without having to register/create an account)?

Note: A malicious user should not be able to type in an order id in the url to view someone elses order.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, `IsValid` depends on at least the `orderid` and some other *key(s)* that uniquely identify "who" is asking.

Even in a *"guest checkout"* there are certain things that orders will have:

- a billing address/data
- a delivery address/data
- likely a user **email address** so the customer can get updates/invoice copies ,etc.
- on that note, an unique invoice number

So you can think of ways to ensure that only the "right" person obtains the info using one or more of the above - perhaps only email (instead of display) info to the requester.

Hth..

Comment: Let's say I want to use the email. Do I pass the email in the ViewBag from the "checkout page" to the "order complete page"? Or do I store the email in the session object? What is the proper MVC way?

Comment: @PussInBoots Unsure what you're referring to, pattern (MVC or whatever) doesn't seem relevant. During a guest checkout session/task/flow, the user is the relevant "person". You'd store/persist order details (including all the info common to almost any "order") so that you can use those data points at some **other time** - re: a day later the guest user queries the status of their order and only provides the order id and some other key/s you persisted.

Comment: I should have been more specific. The question is sorta related to MVC and in particular ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: @PussInBoots Same concept, nothing changes, pattern isn't really relevant - you're still using core HTTP concepts (session/cookies/data, etc). You can create/determine the right "keys" on the "session" (active/current/session id/guid) or some other point in time (POST/GET data, etc).

Comment: Actually what I am after (and which I should have been clear about in my post(s)) is a code snippet that I could use in my application.